# Optimize creating a column from espression in a large dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

Dear StackOverflowers :) , I am trying to calculate a new column in my dataframe, from an expression that uses previous columns as input. I have written a function, but it is taking hours in a 650,000 rows dataframe, while the complete dataset is going to have 3.3 million rows!

I was wondering how I can optimize my code, or if I should just look for some more powerful PC in my department.
Here's an example:

```
testdf99<- data.frame('V1'= c(1:10), 'V2'= c(2,3,4,5,3,2,2,3,8,8))
```

My purpose is to create a Var3 column:

```
my_calculator<- function(input_table){
table0<- input_table
colnames(table0)<- c('Coordinate', 'Var1')
table0$Var2<- table0$Coordinate+table0$Var1-1
table0$Var3<- -99 # as sanity check
#Now let's calculate Var3 at each position
for (i in 1:nrow(table0)){
  #position of i
  i_POS<- table0[i,'Coordinate']
  # Var1 covering i_POS
  table1<- table0[table0$Coordinate<= i_POS & table0$Var2>= i_POS,]
  table0[i, 'Var3']<- max(table1$Var1)}
return(table0)}
```

Creating Var2 seems to be instantaneous, but when I insert Var3 into the function, it goes on for hours (~650,000 rows).
I would appreciate any suggestion for better code that could sensibly speed up the calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my attempt to convert your function into apply style loops.

```
f1 <- function(table0){
  for (i in 1:nrow(table0)){
    #position of i
    i_POS<- table0[i,'Coordinate']
    # Var1 covering i_POS
    table1<- table0[table0$Coordinate<= i_POS & table0$Var2>= i_POS,]
    table0[i, 'Var3']<- max(table1$Var1)
  }
  table0
}

f2 <- function(table0){
    mutate(table0, lapply(1:10, function(i){ 
      max(table0[table0$Coordinate<= i & table0$Var2>= i,]$Var1)
    }))
}


all.equal(f1(table0), f2(table0))
[1] TRUE
```

Now for some timing:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(f1(table0),f2(table0))

Unit: microseconds
       expr      min        lq      mean    median       uq      max neval
 f1(table0) 1266.691 1317.8750 1693.9076 1602.0810 1872.075 2931.152   100
 f2(table0)   13.892   18.1005   33.1414   26.4715   42.242  123.525   100
```

Edit: you could always include some Rcpp code, this one with the great c++ Armadillo library.

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
vec f3(arma::mat table0) {

  int t0_rows = table0.n_rows;
  vec coord = table0.col(0);
  vec var1 = table0.col(1);
  vec var2 = table0.col(2);
  vec var3 = zeros<vec>(t0_rows);

  for(int i = 0; i < t0_rows; i++){
    var3(i) = max(var1(find((coord <= coord[i]) &&
      var2  >= coord[i])));
  }
  return var3;
}

table0_v3 <- f3(table0)
```

Note that this only creates a single column matrix, which is var3.

Comment: Dear Shayaa,

Thanks for your kind help, and for introducing me to the fantastic package dplyr! It looks amazing, and I am just reading about it. 
I have implemented the script in my main function, and tested the results. Now I am going to run it on the 650k rows dataset and see what happens. From your tests, it should be extremely fast!
In the meanwhile, there's something I do not understand: Why there is no "return" at the end of the function? I tested out, and if I include return(table0), the results are basically ignoring the mutate function. I don't know what I am missing here :( ??

Comment: Because that call to mutate is the function return value. Functions by default return the last call in the body of the function if you do not assign it to a variable. If you want to have a specific return value you can save this mutate call to table0 and then return table0.

Comment: Thank you, it makes sense. I have been running the new function for an hour and 20 minutes by now. Finger crossed, it will end soon :)

Comment: OK, 1 hour and 40 minutes on desktop PC with 8Gb RAM  and Intel Core i7 CPU 3.4GHz 3.4GHz (I guess that means dual core).
I did not time my own script last time, I'm going to run it again. My impression is that your script saved me between 1 to 2 hours.

Comment: Wow, that is a long time. I will edit my answer with a RcppArmadillo version. You are welcome to click the check box by the solution if this helped you.

Comment: Hahaha, now you're way out of my league! Gotta have a look at the Armadillo library and C++ now! I truly appreciate your help. 
Also, I didn't have the chance to time my old function, but thinking back, even the dplyr version probably saved at least 3 hours.
Thanks for showing me better ways to code

Comment: Out of curiosity:
I just added one more variable to the 650K rows dataframe. It involved my usual loop: for (i in 1:nrow(df))  - and a simple mathematical expression that did not need to create a subset dataframe; still requiring   2 variables input from the dataset though. I am working on my puny laptop and was ready to let it run over night, but it finished in ~ 30 minutes. It appears to me that the time-consuming step (in the question I posted) could be the repeated dataframe subsetting. Got to muse on it for a while. Food for though I guess...

Comment: yes, but i did not have your real data. It helps when constructing an example that it minimally reconstruct your data.